# trying to set a label from a method called from a timer on the same form getting error

Tags: c#, timer

I have a timer that, when fired, is to set a label as visible. When I call the the method that does this, it gives the following exception:

Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'Startup2' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

My timer:

```
void GpsTimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
  if (!ServicesConfig.MiscClasses.VerifyInternetAccess.HasInternet())
  {
    toolStripStatusLabel_Status.Text = "Internet not available!!";
    _history.History = "GPS Readings - Internet access not available.";
    HasError();
    return;
  }

  toolStripStatusLabel_Status.Text = "Processing GPS data.";
   _history.History = "GPS Readings - Timer ticked...";
  _gpsTimer.Stop();
  _history.History = "GPS Readings - Timer stopped...";
  var process = new ProcessGpsFile();
  _history.History = "GPS Readings - Timer processing Reading started...";
  if (process.ProcessReading()) HasError();
  _history.History = "GPS Readings - Timer processing Reading finished...";
  _gpsTimer.Start();
  _history.History = "GPS Readings - Timer started.";
  _history.History = "--------------------------------------------------------";
  toolStripStatusLabel_Status.Text = "Process GPS data complete.";
}
```

My method with the label:

```
private void HasError()
{
  pictureBox_Status.Image = Properties.Resources.yellow;
  label_ClickToSeeError.Visible = true;
}
```

I hate to assume but does that mean the timer is running on it's own thread, separate from the  form? How do I fix this?

Thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using a `System.Timers.Timer`, which run on the thread pool.
You should replace that with a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, which runs on the UI thread.